# How does a browser determine what is a "mobile" site vs what is a "desktop" site?

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, desktop

I was building responsiveness into my site and I noticed that when accessing a certain functionality which redirected the user to either the Apple App Store or Google Play based off their user agent string, the site wouldn't work when the browser was rendering it as the "Mobile Version" whereas when I hit "Request Desktop Version" it seemed to work. The only different I've written into the site as far as the two versions are is media queries. This got me to wondering what the parameters are for the browser to determine whether or not a site is the "Mobile" version or the "Desktop" version.

Comment: depends on what approach you are using - if it's responsive then it's based on the media query for certain sizes, if it's adaptive, then it's usually a list of certain user agent strings that are checked.

Comment: Indeed...the *browser* does no such thing....the JS/CSS will determine what is seen

Comment: Right. But as far as changing the "Request Mobile" and "Request Desktop" functionality, what is the difference as far as the browser is seeing?

Comment: Again, the browser isn't *seeing* anything - it's displaying what it's told to display.

Answer (score 0):

One way ive used to determine what device the user is using is by the DOM navigator object. If you type *navigator.userAgent* into your js console, it gives you some info on what kind of device and hardware the user is on. [Here is some more information on the user agent header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent#Firefox_UA_string) and [Here is W3's page on the Navigator object.](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/obj_navigator.asp) Hope that helps out some.

Answer (score -1):

Here is code that works for what you need

```js
(function(a){(jQuery.browser=jQuery.browser||{}).mobile=/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var isMobile = {
  Android: function() {
   return navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i);
  },
  BlackBerry: function() {
   return navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i);
  },
  iOS: function() {
   return navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i);
  },
  Opera: function() {
   return navigator.userAgent.match(/Opera Mini/i);
  },
  Windows: function() {
   return navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/i);
  },
  any: function() {
   return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Opera() || isMobile.Windows());
  }
 };
 if(isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry()){
  window.location.href = "AndroidAPP";
 } 
 else if(isMobile.iOS()){
  window.location.href = ("iOSAPP");
 }
 else
 {
  window.location.href=("Your desktop site")
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for the code, but I am just inquiring on what the different parameters are for a browser to deem a site "mobile" or "desktop."

Answer (score -1):

I usually use Javascript:

```
var mobile = true;

if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/iPad/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    mobile = true;
}

// mobile can be used wherever now
if(mobile) {
    // do special styling
}
```